# CRUD operation within multi step form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-sessions

I am not sure what is the exact name of what I am about to describe. Nevertheless, I am trying to replicate something like below picture. Where a client is able to add, delete and adjust as many users as he wants while seeing overview in the table below.

I thought the best way to go about is to create a view of a form that is called when you 'Add new user'. Thereafter, you would have a view with the table below where you just loop through users to show information you want (User, Amount, Edit...).

My question is how to go about it when I want to keep these created users separate from each client. In another words, if you and I both create users on the app, I do not want to show you users I created and vice versa.

Is storing this in session a viable way or are there any better and more efficient approaches?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88wK6.png)

Comment: Have you a second model of user for the app or you use the same User model for the app and the project ?

Comment: I have a second model of user for the app. There is one model for user* that can create users shown in the picture.

Comment: So you have to filter base on the user Which have created the "User for app" for that you must have a user field with ForeignKey(User) relationship and make filtering base on that

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a good solution. The only problem is that I do not require users to log in or any other info as it is on a website. Maybe I could use something like an IP address